# Retrieving data from sql file in java

Tags: java, sql, database

I need some guidance on how to retrieving data from a database.
The database is called Drug Combination DataBase and so far I'm just using a small text file that contains a small portion of the data, but the complete database is available as a 14mb sql-file. Can I load this in an efficient way during run-time in my java application so I can look up a few entries? I've never used an sql-file to retrieve data in java before so I don't know what is the best strategy.
By the way, I'm creating an application that reads large graphs and another xml database so memory usage is fairly high.

Comment: What do you mean by "sql file?" The way you handle this is different if it's a CSV, Sqlite db, or Mysql flat file.

Comment: I'm referring to the contents of the DCDB.zip at this page: [DCDB2 download page](http://www.cls.zju.edu.cn/dcdb/download.jsf)

Comment: Looks like they also provide a tab-separated version, so the answer will depend a lot on how you plan to use the data. Is this a one-time thing, or for a system you're going to query?

Comment: I need to retrieve data each time a user uploads, creates or changes graphs which will happen multiple times while the app is running.

Answer (score 1):

the way to connect a Java program to a database is through JDBC. the file needs to be read int and saved to a database like MySQL or PostgresQL in order to be accessed. check out this link for a good tutorial:
[jdbc tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/)